# How to make complex URL works in Swift 5's Safari Services for WebKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, url, webkit

I have a complicated URL of this sort

https://dashboard.companyABC.com:8080/single/?appid=522ee00f-7752-4be7-9346-7bd593c064b9&obj=ataQUe&opt=ctxmenu,currsel&select=$::%3DDual(Year(%5BRequested%20Date%5D)%2CYearStart(%5BRequested%20Date%5D)),43466%22%20style=%22border:none;width:100%;height:100%;%22%3E

How can I put it into our safari services or WebKit call?

I tried this:

```
let myURL = #"https://dashboard.companyABC.com:8080/single/?appid=522ee00f-7752-4be7-9346-7bd593c064b9&obj=ataQUe&opt=ctxmenu,currsel&select=$::%3DDual(Year(%5BRequested%20Date%5D)%2CYearStart(%5BRequested%20Date%5D)),43466%22%20style=%22border:none;width:100%;height:100%;%22%3E"#
```

then:

```
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: myURL)
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

Nothing came out in the web view. I suspect my myURL somehow screwed up.

Thanks.